# Classpath problems with JSR223 scripting in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jsr223

I am trying to understand an issue I'm seeing with JSR223 scripting when running inside Tomcat.  I'm using the Java scripting engine, but I believe the problem applies more generally (I've seen a similar problem with the reference JS engine as well).  The script I am passing for evaluation has this as the first line:

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

This fails with the message:

```
package javax.servlet.http does not exist
```

So, digging into the source code of the Java scripting engine, I know why this is happening - it passes my script text to JavaCompiler, specifying as the classpath what it retrieved from `java.class.path`, but because Tomcat does its own thing as far as classloaders and classpaths are concerned, the only thing that contains is `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/bootstrap.jar`.

It is possible to override the classpath that will be used by the scripting engine, but that then just presents me with my next problem - how can I discover, at runtime, what claspath Tomcat is using?

It seems like I must be missing something obvious here, because as far as I can tell this is going to happen to anybody who tries to do any kind of serious scripting in a web application, and yet I have I have searched for hours for discussions in this area and can't find anybody even asking the question...